# Call Instance Method from Subclass Constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, instance, subclass

I am writing a simple blackjack program that I plan to expand as I get better with Java. My course did not cover inheritance very well, and they did not bother to discuss subclasses at all.

When the player decides to end the game, I want to print out the player's total chip count. Whenever I write the print statement, I get the error:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field alice.

I have no idea what Eclipse means by non-static field, because the only `static` I'm familiar with is in a top-level method. Do I have to create an entirely separate class named `Player` to make the reference?

I've attached a snippet of code pertaining to the subclass and the entire main method. Additionally, this is a personal project, not homework, to help build my portfolio, so any other advice that you deem worthy, I welcome. Thanks for the help.

```
public class BlackJack 
{

public class Player extends BlackJack
{
    public int wallet;
    private int hand;

    public Player(int playerHand, int playerWallet)
    {
        wallet = playerWallet;
        hand = playerHand;
    }

    public int getWallet()
    { return wallet; }
}

Player alice = new Player(0, 250);

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Welcome to Black Jack. Type begin to get started.");

    String begin = "begin";
    String end = "end";
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (!keyboard.equals(end))
        {

        }
    System.out.println("You walked away with $" + alice.getWallet() + ". Thanks for playing!");
}
```

}

Comment: try doing `static Player alice = new Player(0, 250);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `alice` is being used in `main()`, which is static, `main()` doesn't "exist" inside an object, but your variable `alice` must be inside one. Do this change to your code to execute a non-static method `run()` "inside" an object (run has the same code as main, it was just changed to a non-static method):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new BlackJack().run(args);
}

public void run(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Black Jack. Type begin to get started.");

    String begin = "begin";
    String end = "end";
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (!keyboard.equals(end))
    {

    }
    System.out.println("You walked away with $" + alice.getWallet() + ". Thanks for playing!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your alice variable is declared non-static, but is being used in the static main method, a no-no. Some may suggest that you make alice a static variable, but I advise against this. Instead consider making your main method very short -- just enough to get the program up and running, and have another class, perhaps a Game class, one with non-static methods and fields, actually run the game. The main method will create a Game instance and then call a method on this Game instance to have it start the whole game.

As an aside, I can't see how you would want to have Player extend the BlackJack class, since the concept of a Player isn't a more specialized concept of a "BlackJack" whatever that may be.

Comment: The `extends BlackJack` is a mistake. I tried something, and Eclipse opted to add that as a fix. I forgot to remove it.

Comment: @rice2007: you also seem to be nesting the Player class inside of the BlackJack class, something that shouldn't be done either.

Comment: @ Hovercraft: when is it appropriate to nest another class inside of class? I've seen it happen, and this is literally the first time I have ever nested classes.

Comment: @rice2007: At your stage, I recommend only doing it for private inner classes or anonymous inner classes. Otherwise make separate classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `alice` is declared without a `static` modifier. This means that this object can only be used when an instance of the containing class has been instantiated.

You, however, use `alice.getWallet()` in the `public static void main()` method, which is `static`. Since static means that this method can be called without creating an object of the enclosing class, this would mean that the method would try to access the non-static object `alice` which can't be accessed.

If you make `alice` static, it'll work.

A better approach is to just let your program start in the `main()` method and go to a non-static `Game` class or something similar. No hassle with static modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Move `Player alice = new Player(0, 250);` inside the main method !